# PCFMessageAgent - Authentication

Tags: java, ibm-mq

How does the **PCFMessageAgent** with the following constructor gets authenticated. What are the user/configuration permissions required to be set. I connect to MQ of version 8.0.0.4.

```
public PCFMessageAgent(java.lang.String host,
           int port,
           java.lang.String channel)
            throws MQException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not provide enough details to give an exact answer.  That constructor does not allow for authentication, it connects to the host/port/channel specified but does not pass a username/password or allow for the use of a cetificate.

If the channel on the queue manager does not require CONNAUTH (ex: "CHKCLNT(OPTIONAL)") or TLS (ex: SSLCIPH/SSLPEER) and you are not blocked by CHLAUTH rules, you may be able to connect.

To determine what user MQ would use for authorization would depend on what user your java process is running under, the MCAUSER attribute of the channel, and any CHLAUTH rules that could map you to a different MCAUSER.  Based on the final MCAUSER value, MQ would check if you have permission to the SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE and the model queue used to create a temporary dynamic queue for replies.

---

If you want to provide a username and password or use certificates you would need to create a MQQueueManager and pass this instead of host/port/channel using this constructor:

> ```
> PCFMessageAgent(MQQueueManager qmanager)
> ```
>
> Initializes a new PCFMessageAgent with an existing queue manager connection.